# How to make this script read all subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I found [script opening random files](http://forums.majorgeeks.com/index.php?threads/batch-program-how-could-i-open-a-random-image-from-a-specified-folder.181574/).
I changed one thing and now it open random file from C:/
Can somebody tell me how to change it to open random file from C:/ and all subfolders?

```
@echo off & setlocal
:: start of main
rem Set your path here:
set "workDir=C:\"

rem Read the %random%, two times is'nt a mistake! Why? Ask Bill.
rem In fact at the first time %random% is nearly the same.
@set /a "rdm=%random%"
set /a "rdm=%random%"

rem Push to
pushd "%workDir%"

rem Count all files in your path. (dir with /b shows only the filenames)
set /a "counter=0"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b ^|find "."') do call :sub1

rem This function gives a value from 1 to upper bound of files
set /a "rdNum=(%rdm%*%counter%/32767)+1"

rem Start a random file
set /a "counter=0"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b ^|find "."') do set "fileName=%%i" &call :sub2

rem Pop back from your path.
popd "%workDir%"

goto :eof
:: end of main

:: start of sub1
:sub1
rem For each found file set counter + 1.
set /a "counter+=1"
goto :eof
:: end of sub1

:: start of sub2
:sub2
rem 1st: count again,
rem 2nd: if counted number equals random number then start the file.
set /a "counter+=1"
if %counter%==%rdNum% (start "" "%fileName%")
goto :eof
:: end of sub2

:: -snap--- end of batch
```

Comment: Should every file have an equal chance of being selected, or is it OK if higher-up files in the directory tree are more likely?

Comment: Yep, every file should have equal chance of being opened.

Comment: `dir /s` - `/s` Displays files in specified directory and all subdirectories.

Comment: Hello! Since we're not a script writing service, we need you to provide us more specifics about where you're getting stuck, beyond code you copied from someplace. So where are you getting stuck exactly, while implementing the changes you are asking for?  What have you attempted already, and what were the results of those attempts?  Without that info, and work on your part, this question will acquire down-votes, and may be closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 1):

You need the `/s` switch

Change

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b ^|find "."') do call :sub1
```

to

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s ^|find "."') do call :sub1
```

and change

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b ^|find "."') do set "fileName=%%i" &call :sub2
```

to

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s ^|find "."') do set "fileName=%%i" &call :sub2
```

Comment: Hi k073I, did this help?

Comment: I don't know. I let it work for 20 mins and nothing.

Comment: For being honest I tried it some time ago